# Symfony, form with fields from different entities

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create a form with Symfony using 2 differents Entities.

I want to display the fields from the entity "Candidats"
and the fields from the Entity "Applications"

I did create the "applications" fields just fine, but when I tried to add the new fields for "Candidats" I got a error :

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createView" of class
> "Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder".

My AppController code is :

```
/**
     * @Route("/form", name="form")
     */
    public function formulaire()
    {
        $application = new Applications();
        $candidat = new Candidats();

        $formCandidat = $this->createFormBuilder($candidat)
                            ->add("nom")
                            ->add("prenom")
                            ->add("email");

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($application)
                    ->add("poste", ChoiceType::class, [
                        'choices'  => [
                        'Choisissez un poste ...' => null,
                        'Chef de Projet' => 'Chef de Projet',
                        'Secrétaire' => 'Secrétaire',
                        'Assistant' => 'Assistant',
                        ],
                    ])
                    ->add('pdf', FileType::class, [
                        'label' => 'Fiche de candidature (PDF)',
        
                        // unmapped means that this field is not associated to any entity property
                        'mapped' => false,
        
                        // make it optional so you don't have to re-upload the PDF file
                        // every time you edit the Product details
                        'required' => false,

                        'constraints' => [
                            new File([
                                'maxSize' => '1024k',
                                'mimeTypes' => [
                                    'application/pdf',
                                    'application/x-pdf',
                                ],
                                'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid PDF document',
                            ])
                        ]
                    ])
                    ->getForm();

        return $this->render('app/form.html.twig', [
            
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'formCandidat' => $formCandidat->createView(),
        
            
        ]);
    }
   
}
```

I might be completely wrong on how I tryy to do it!

anyone see how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is trigerred by this line

```
'formCandidat' => $formCandidat->createView(),
```

You didn't call getForm() for $formCandidat so it is still a FormBuilder object

Change this

```
$formCandidat = $this->createFormBuilder($candidat)
                    ->add("nom")
                    ->add("prenom")
                    ->add("email");
```

to this

```
$formCandidat = $this->createFormBuilder($candidat)
                    ->add("nom")
                    ->add("prenom")
                    ->add("email")
                    ->getForm();
```